# Struts 2: ui.theme changes in struts.properties are not getting reflected

Tags: java, properties, struts2, themes, xml-configuration

I am creating a project using maven as below

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DgroupId=com.myApplication -DartifactId=MyApplication -
DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-starter -
DarchetypeVersion=2.3.7
```

After that in `struts.properties` file I am changing

```
struts.ui.theme=xhtml
```

to

```
struts.ui.theme=simple
```

but when I run the application the `simple` theme doesn't apply.

Comment: Try do define it inside struts.xml `<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />`. Also how do you check that simple theme is not applied?

Comment: It creating default table structure for control same as for theme=xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the files `struts.properties` `struts.xml` in the project and in deployment. Check that every found file contains necessary changes before run and after run. And `struts.xml` doesn't contain `<constant name="struts.ui.theme"`. If it doesn't help try to search disk or computer for keyword `struts.ui.theme`. HTH

Comment: <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" /> worked for me but I don't know why struts.properties file is not recognized.